# from.import views ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

from django.urls import re_path as url
from . import views

urlpatterns=[

```
url('home/',views.home,name="home"),
url('marketing_courses/',views.marketingCourses,name="Marketing courses"),
url('privacy_policy/',views.privacyPolicy,name="Privacy policy"),
url('blog/',views.blog,name="blog"),
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Please add an empty `__init__.py` in folder where urls.py is.